# How to binding TextBlock with XML?

Tags: wpf, xml, xaml, xaml-binding

I want make a system of change language witch change XML File.

I have a `XML` file, this struct is this:

```
<List>
    <File>Arquivo</File>
    <Edit>Editar</Edit>
    <View>Visual</View>
</List>
```

In my `WPF`:

```
<TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="File" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="File">
<TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="Edit" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="Edit">
<TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="View" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="View">
```

So, How to binding this `TextBlock's` text with `XML` file values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you'll need to create [`XmlDataProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.xmldataprovider.aspx), something like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <XmlDataProvider x:Key="InventoryData">
      <x:XData>
          <List xmlns="">
              <File>Arquivo</File>
              <Edit>Editar</Edit>
              <View>Visual</View>
          </List>
      </x:XData>
  </XmlDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
```

You can also load it from extenral XML file by specifing `XmlDataProvider.Source`. When you have your source then you bind it by specifying `Binding.Source` as `InventoryData` and [`Binding.XPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx) to node that interests you, something like this:

```
<StackPanel>
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource InventoryData}, XPath=List/File}"/>
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource InventoryData}, XPath=List/Edit}"/>
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource InventoryData}, XPath=List/View}"/>
</StackPanel>
```